# Change body when mysql not connected

Tags: php, mysql

i want to change body background color and write 'ALERT!!' when there is mysql_connetcion problem..

as like:

```
$vtbaglan = @mysql_connect($vt_host,$vt_user,$vt_pass) or die("<body style='background:red’>Connection Alert!!</body>“);
```

do you have any idea, how can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please close the question by accepting the answer. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
//(...)
if($link == false){ ?>
   <body style='background:red'>Connection Alert!!</body>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct the closing quotes.

```
die("<body style='background:red’>Connection Alert!!</body>“);
```

To

```
die("<body style='background:red'>Connection Alert!!</body>");
```

Please note there are two closing quotes.

1. 'background:red`’`
2. Connection Alert!!`“`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should not be using `mysql_*` functions.

To make it all manageable, you should not die() but check if the connection succeeded. There's a good example on PHP's manual page for [mysqli_connect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");

if (!$link) { // Connection failed
    // Show your error stuff
    exit;
}

// Do your application

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below line,

```
$vtbaglan = @mysql_connect($vt_host,$vt_user,$vt_pass) or die("<body style='background:red'>Connection Alert!!</body>");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `javascript` is good option :-

```
<?php
$link = @mysql_connect('localhost','username','password');
if($link == false){ 
echo 'Connection Alert!!';
?>

<script>
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
</script>
<?php } 
?>

<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```